# Android set height and width of Custom view programmatically

Tags: android, view, height, width, parameters

I have created a custom view named `Graphview` . Here is the structure for the GraphView class.

```
public class GraphView extends View {

    public GraphView(Context context, float[] values, String title, String[] horlabels, String[] verlabels, boolean type) {
        super(context);
                ........
   }

   ..................
   .................
}
```

I have added the view in a tablerow using `addview()`. It is working fine. Now I want to set height and width for the `GraphView`. How to do that?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

If you know the exact size of the view, just use `setLayoutParams()`:

```
graphView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));
```

Or in Kotlin:

```
graphView.layoutParams = LayoutParams(width, height)
```

However, if you need a more flexible approach you can override `onMeasure()` to measure the view more precisely depending on the space available and layout constraints (`wrap_content`, `match_parent`, or a fixed size). You can find more details about `onMeasure()` in the [android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#custom).

Comment: Would be helpful to know which LayoutParams you are importing there.

Comment: The `LayoutParams` should be from the layout where the `graphView` is placed. For example if in the XML layout file `graphView` is placed inside `RelativeLayout`, then you should use `new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height)`

Comment: What if the `graphView` inside a `ScrollView` in Kotlin?

Answer (score 244):

You can set height and width like this:

```
myGraphView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));
```

Comment: You should make sure the LayoutParam class you use is from the correct parent Layout class. For example, if your GraphView is contained in a LinearLayout, you need to use the LinearLayout.LayoutParams class.

Comment: This also does work and ensures you use the correct LayoutParams class: simply do `myGraphView.getLayoutParams().height = 100;`.

Comment: Generally making absolute statements with hardcoded meaningless numbers leads to trouble. Better to make relative statements as much as possible, e.g. with `fill_parent` etc.

Comment: If you do `this.getLayoutParams().height = 100`, make sure to follow it by `this.setLayoutParams(this.getLayoutParams())`, otherwise it will not do anything (useful).

Comment: I think it's odd that this answer is getting more points. While it's easier it's much less modular; if you'd like to use your view in a different place you'd need to hardcode those width/height values there as well. Be careful about using this.

Comment: Thanks @yincrash for pointing that out. It seems odd that I need to use the parent view' class (RelativeLayout in my case) instead of the parent class of my custom view (SurfaceView in my case) though

Comment: We do need to calculate the size of a view programmatically when the default params do not fit the need of program. That why we need this answer. Thank you Eric Nordvik, you helped a lot.

Answer (score 95):

you can set the height and width of a view in a relative layout like this

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 130;
view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: you do not need to set layoutparam  again. It gets reflected automatically. This is the advantage of object oriented approach.

Comment: @Dipendra the call to `setLayoutParams()` is required because it invokes other methods such as `resolveLayoutParams()` and `requestLayout()`

Comment: giving exception as in onCreate getLayoutParams() is null value.So params.height cause exception

Comment: You should refer the view for which you have to set the height.  Check if you are pointing to the same view

Comment: Getting the `layoutParams` at a view's initiation will be a NPE, please explain at what point to you run this?

Answer (score 30):

On Kotlin you can set width and height of any view directly using their virtual properties:

```
someView.layoutParams.width = 100
someView.layoutParams.height = 200
```

Comment: This doesn't work because it won't update the UI

Comment: you might need to add `someView.requestLayout()` right after that to apply the changes.

Answer (score 30):

If you're using Kotlin, you can also use the following code which applies your given lambda on the current layout params:

```kotlin
someView.updateLayoutParams {
    height = 200
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
spin12.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 120));
```

`spin12` is your spinner and **200**,**120** is `width` and `height` for your `spinner`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a Kotlin based version, assuming that the parent view is an instance of `LinearLayout`.

```
someView.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 200)
```

This allows to set the width and height (`100` and `200`) in a single line.

Answer (score 1):

### Typical real-world example:

in a Fragment:

```
private LinearLayout images;
...

float dpf = TypedValue.applyDimension(
  TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 69, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        SpecialImage s = new SpecialImage(getActivity());
        images.addView(s);
        s.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
         (int) dpf, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    }
```

1. useless unless use DIP conversion
2. this usually happens in fragments, notice `getActivity()`
3. you're usually adding a few into a linear layout or similar
4. typically one dimension is "fill parent"
5. you must use the "correct" `LayoutParams` (ie, `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` in the example

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the solution by @MorganWilde. You can use the following code if you want to use WRAP_CONTENT/MATCH_PARENT.

```
someView.layoutParams =
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
     ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
     ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
```

Answer (score -1):

here this class take care of everything you need for working with views programmatically

```
public class LayoutHelper {

public static final int MATCH_PARENT = -1;
public static final int WRAP_CONTENT = -2;

private static int getSize(float size) {
    return (int) (size < 0 ? size : AndroidUtilities.dp(size));
}

public static ScrollView.LayoutParams createScroll(int width, int height, int gravity) {
    return new ScrollView.LayoutParams(getSize(width), getSize(height), gravity);
}

public static ScrollView.LayoutParams createScroll(int width, int height, int gravity, float leftMargin, float topMargin, float rightMargin, float bottomMargin) {
    ScrollView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ScrollView.LayoutParams(getSize(width), getSize(height), gravity);
    layoutParams.leftMargin = AndroidUtilities.dp(leftMargin);
    layoutParams.topMargin = AndroidUtilities.dp(topMargin);
    layoutParams.rightMargin = AndroidUtilities.dp(rightMargin);
    layoutParams.bottomMargin = AndroidUtilities.dp(bottomMargin);
    return layoutParams;
}

public static FrameLayout.LayoutParams createFrame(int width, float height, int gravity, float leftMargin, float topMargin, float rightMargin, float bottomMargin) {
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(getSize(width), getSize(height), gravity);
    layoutParams.setMargins(AndroidUtilities.dp(leftMargin), AndroidUtilities.dp(topMargin), AndroidUtilities.dp(rightMargin), AndroidUtilities.dp(bottomMargin));
    return layoutParams;
}

public static FrameLayout.LayoutParams createFrame(int width, int height, int gravity) {
    return new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(getSize(width), getSize(height), gravity);
}

public static FrameLayout.LayoutParams createFrame(int width, float height) {
    return new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(getSize(width), getSize(height));
}

public static RelativeLayout.LayoutParams createRelative(float width, float height, int leftMargin, int topMargin, int rightMargin, int bottomMargin, int alignParent, int alignRelative, int anchorRelative) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(getSize(width), getSize(height));
    if (alignParent >= 0) {
        layoutParams.addRule(alignParent);
    }
    if (alignRelative >= 0 && anchorRelative >= 0) {
        layoutParams.addRule(alignRelative, anchorRelative);
    }
    layoutParams.leftMargin = AndroidUtilities.dp(leftMargin);
    layoutParams.topMargin = AndroidUtilities.dp(topMargin);
    layoutParams.rightMargin = AndroidUtilities.dp(rightMargin);
    layoutParams.bottomMargin = AndroidUtilities.dp(bottomMargin);
    return layoutParams;
}

public static RelativeLayout.LayoutParams createRelative(int width, int height, int leftMargin, int topMargin, int rightMargin, int bottomMargin) {
    return createRelative(width, height, leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin, -1, -1, -1);
}

public static RelativeLayout.LayoutParams createRelative(int width, int height, int leftMargin, int topMargin, int rightMargin, int bottomMargin, int alignParent) {
    return createRelative(width, height, leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin, alignParent, -1, -1);
}

public static RelativeLayout.LayoutParams createRelative(float width, float height, int leftMargin, int topMargin, int rightMargin, int bottomMargin, int alignRelative, int anchorRelative) {
    return createRelative(width, height, leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin, -1, alignRelative, anchorRelative);
}

public static RelativeLayout.LayoutParams createRelative(int width, int height, int alignParent, int alignRelative, int anchorRelative) {
    return createRelative(width, height, 0, 0, 0, 0, alignParent, alignRelative, anchorRelative);
}

public static RelativeLayout.LayoutParams createRelative(int width, int height) {
    return createRelative(width, height, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1);
}

public static RelativeLayout.LayoutParams createRelative(int width, int height, int alignParent) {
    return createRelative(width, height, 0, 0, 0, 0, alignParent, -1, -1);
}

public static RelativeLayout.LayoutParams createRelative(int width, int height, int alignRelative, int anchorRelative) {
    return createRelative(width, height, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, alignRelative, anchorRelative);
}

public static LinearLayout.LayoutParams createLinear(int width, int height, float weight, int gravity, int leftMargin, int topMargin, int rightMargin, int bottomMargin) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getSize(width), getSize(height), weight);
    layoutParams.setMargins(AndroidUtilities.dp(leftMargin), AndroidUtilities.dp(topMargin), AndroidUtilities.dp(rightMargin), AndroidUtilities.dp(bottomMargin));
    layoutParams.gravity = gravity;
    return layoutParams;
}

public static LinearLayout.LayoutParams createLinear(int width, int height, float weight, int leftMargin, int topMargin, int rightMargin, int bottomMargin) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getSize(width), getSize(height), weight);
    layoutParams.setMargins(AndroidUtilities.dp(leftMargin), AndroidUtilities.dp(topMargin), AndroidUtilities.dp(rightMargin), AndroidUtilities.dp(bottomMargin));
    return layoutParams;
}

public static LinearLayout.LayoutParams createLinear(int width, int height, int gravity, int leftMargin, int topMargin, int rightMargin, int bottomMargin) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getSize(width), getSize(height));
    layoutParams.setMargins(AndroidUtilities.dp(leftMargin), AndroidUtilities.dp(topMargin), AndroidUtilities.dp(rightMargin), AndroidUtilities.dp(bottomMargin));
    layoutParams.gravity = gravity;
    return layoutParams;
}

public static LinearLayout.LayoutParams createLinear(int width, int height, float leftMargin, float topMargin, float rightMargin, float bottomMargin) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getSize(width), getSize(height));
    layoutParams.setMargins(AndroidUtilities.dp(leftMargin), AndroidUtilities.dp(topMargin), AndroidUtilities.dp(rightMargin), AndroidUtilities.dp(bottomMargin));
    return layoutParams;
}

public static LinearLayout.LayoutParams createLinear(int width, int height, float weight, int gravity) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getSize(width), getSize(height), weight);
    layoutParams.gravity = gravity;
    return layoutParams;
}

public static LinearLayout.LayoutParams createLinear(int width, int height, int gravity) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getSize(width), getSize(height));
    layoutParams.gravity = gravity;
    return layoutParams;
}

public static LinearLayout.LayoutParams createLinear(int width, int height, float weight) {
    return new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getSize(width), getSize(height), weight);
}

public static LinearLayout.LayoutParams createLinear(int width, int height) {
    return new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getSize(width), getSize(height));
}
```

}

and you can use it like this:

```
        frameLayout.addView(
        emptyLayout,
        LayoutHelper.createFrame(
            LayoutHelper.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutHelper.WRAP_CONTENT,
            Gravity.CENTER
        )
    );
```