# How to set width and height for custom view in programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, classcastexception

I have created a custom view named MyDraw ,this is my MyDraw code,

```
public class MyDraw extends View {


    public MyDraw(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public MyDraw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }

    public MyDraw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }
         ........................................
}
```

I have added the view in XML file using package name. It is working fine. Now I want to set height and width for the MyDraw in run time,for that i have used following code,

```
mMyDraw.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(220, 300));
```

but i got Exception like,

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams

How to solve this exception?
please help me..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android set height and width of Custom view programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042197/android-set-height-and-width-of-custom-view-programmatically)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Override the `onMeasure()` method, have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#custom)

Answer (score 22):

You must override the onMeasure() method of the View.

For a nice example you can check here: http://kahdev.wordpress.com/2008/09/13/making-a-custom-android-button-using-a-custom-view/

And a very cool video that I would recommend is here: http://marakana.com/forums/android/general/563.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Isn't it the same answer as mine? Do you think adding some other link is making it different answer?

Comment: When started writing the answer, you hadn't answer yet. If you feel better if I remove the answer I have no problem. In any case the user can vote your answer.

Comment: If you think you need not to remove the answer I've no problem. In fact a lot of time I faced same thing (Someone answered while I was writing the same) :)

Comment: Adding extra links does help indeed. Look at the vote count :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way:
based on our custom view parent class we can use layout param.

for example if our custom view is extended from FrameLayout:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) findViewById(R.id.root).getLayoutParams();
params.width = newwidth;
params.height = newHeight;
setLayoutParams(params);
```

where "R.id.root" is id of our root view in custom_view.xml that in this case is FrameLayout.