# How to make the height of a dynamically created TextView exactly 50dp in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I want to make the height of a dynamically created TextView to be 50dp. I tried making a `dimens.xml` file with the code

```
<dimen name="imageview_height">50dp</dimen>
```

And then I use

```
int pixels = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.imageview_height);
```

and finally on the generated TextView I simply use.

```
textView.setHeight(pixels);
```

However when I run it, my app crashes and says *app name* keeps stopping.

Comment: post your crash log plz.

Comment: It'll good if you post error log.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it with this:

```
textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));
```

But there are different **LayoutParams** depending on the layout type. Use the layout that your view is in. Ex: if your view is in a **LinearLayout**, use **LinearLayout.LayoutParams**

See this post for more info: [Android set height and width of Custom view programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042197/android-set-height-and-width-of-custom-view-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

Android throws exception when either height or width is not set programmatically

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) someLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 130;
someLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

so by the above  code, we are getting the layout params of the view itself and then set the height programmatically

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using the following

```
int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 5, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: Since I am still learning, I may be wrong and maybe I am wrong. It's nice gesture to tell the reason for the sake of others' learning to comment the reason of downvote.

Comment: I suppose that your answer was downvoted, because it doesn't help to solve the problem. The OP knows how to calculate dp, but struggles with an exception. The correct approach would be to ask for a stacktrace and help to track down the exception.

Answer (score -1):

## Calculation from  dps -> pixel  ......

```
final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int pixels = (int) (dps * scale + 0.5f);
```

Then set that pixel for programatic use...